# Points are hidden when entering them by command in GeoGebra

Tags: javascript, css, geogebra

I´m testing geogebra in its "Offline and Self-Hosted Solution" mode which can be found in the following link: https://wiki.geogebra.org/es/Referencia:Incrustaci%C3%B3n_de_Aplicaciones_GeoGebra

Incluying the script

```
<script src="GeoGebra/deployggb.js"></script>
```

And the code

```
ggbApp.setHTML5Codebase('js/lib/GeoGebra/HTML5/5.0/web3d/');
```

The problem I found in this mode is that when I add those through the command input neither the name nor the value is displayed.

Attached an image where the problem is shown:
[image: image where the problem is shown]

The environment where the problem can be replicated is as follows:
https://anayarojo.github.io/geogebra/?type=graphing

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: https://help.geogebra.org/topic/los-puntos-se-ocultan-al-ingresarlos-por-comando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Michael Borcherds](https://help.geogebra.org/profile/861) Commented that bug is fixed in the latest version (v523)

The last version it's downloadable in http://download.geogebra.org/installers/5.0/?C=M;O=D

Credits
[@ Noel Lambert](https://help.geogebra.org/profile/5)